# conan Eigen3 fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake, conan

After switching to conan2 I cannot figure out how to correctly include Eigen3.
I use examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project to demonstrate the problem.

I added:
`eigen/3.4.0`
to examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/conanfile.txt
`find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)`
to CMakeLists.txt
and
`#include <Eigen/Core>`
to main.c.

When running "run_example.sh" I get:

fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

I would be very appreciative for any help.

conan --version
version: 2.0.14
python version: 3.10.12

Comment: The Eigen is ported to Conan 2.x already. Something is wrong with your configuration, did you link to the cmake target `Eigen3::Eigen`? Could you please share your conanfile.txt, CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp content? Plus, share you entire build log.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you fo your reply.

Below you find everything you asked for. Eigen3 is installed correctly
When adding the Eigen3 include path to CMakeList.txt

```
include_directories(
    /home/wester/.conan2/p/eigen3d88c0279cc26/p/include/eigen3
)
```

the build works

Thank you very much for your help.

Rolf

**conanfile.txt**

```
[requires]
zlib/1.2.11
eigen/3.4.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main(void) {
    char buffer_in [256] = {"Conan is a MIT-licensed, Open Source package manager for C and C++ development, "
                            "allowing development teams to easily and efficiently manage their packages and "
                            "dependencies across platforms and build systems."};
    char buffer_out [256] = {0};

    z_stream defstream;
    defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    defstream.avail_in = (uInt) strlen(buffer_in);
    defstream.next_in = (Bytef *) buffer_in;
    defstream.avail_out = (uInt) sizeof(buffer_out);
    defstream.next_out = (Bytef *) buffer_out;

    deflateInit(&defstream, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    deflate(&defstream, Z_FINISH);
    deflateEnd(&defstream);

    printf("Uncompressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(buffer_in));
    printf("Compressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(buffer_out));

    printf("ZLIB VERSION: %s\n", zlibVersion());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(compressor CXX)

find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

**run_example.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
pushd "$BASEDIR"

rm -rf build

conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
./compressor
```

**output**

```
./run_example.sh 
++ dirname ./run_example.sh
+ BASEDIR=.
+ pushd .
~/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project ~/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project
+ rm -rf build
+ conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing

======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=11
os=Linux

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=11
os=Linux


======== Computing dependency graph ========
zlib/1.2.11: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
zlib/1.2.11: Checking remote: conancenter
zlib/1.2.11: Downloaded recipe revision dc0e384f0551386cd76dc29cc964c95e
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/conanfile.txt
Requirements
    eigen/3.4.0#2e192482a8acff96fe34766adca2b24c - Cache
    zlib/1.2.11#dc0e384f0551386cd76dc29cc964c95e - Downloaded (conancenter)

======== Computing necessary packages ========
Requirements
    eigen/3.4.0#2e192482a8acff96fe34766adca2b24c:da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#b2e7c2d86c5d1dbefc534889aa72e12c - Cache
    zlib/1.2.11#dc0e384f0551386cd76dc29cc964c95e:b647c43bfefae3f830561ca202b6cfd935b56205#d17420fef9f34ec3ee1f6b8997c83415 - Download (conancenter)

======== Installing packages ========

-------- Downloading 1 package --------
zlib/1.2.11: Retrieving package b647c43bfefae3f830561ca202b6cfd935b56205 from remote 'conancenter' 
zlib/1.2.11: Package installed b647c43bfefae3f830561ca202b6cfd935b56205
zlib/1.2.11: Downloaded package revision d17420fef9f34ec3ee1f6b8997c83415
eigen/3.4.0: Already installed! (1 of 2)
WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that will be removed in Conan 2.X:
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.names' used in: zlib/1.2.11, eigen/3.4.0

======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.txt: Writing generators to /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.txt: Preset 'conan-release' added to CMakePresets.json. Invoke it manually using 'cmake --preset conan-release' if using CMake>=3.23
conanfile.txt: If your CMake version is not compatible with CMakePresets (<3.23) call cmake like: 'cmake <path> -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: CMakePresets.json
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: ../CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.txt: Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.txt: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.sh', 'conanrun.sh']
Install finished successfully
+ cd build
+ cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- Using Conan toolchain: /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build/conan_toolchain.cmake
-- Conan toolchain: C++ Standard 17 with extensions ON
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Conan: Target declared 'ZLIB::ZLIB'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'Eigen3::Eigen'
######## /home/wester/.conan2/p/zlib0d40682819e93/p/include;/home/wester/.conan2/p/eigen3d88c0279cc26/p/include/eigen3 #####''
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build
+ cmake --build .
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/src/main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

**cd build && make VERBOSE=1**

```
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project -B/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build/CMakeFiles /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build'
cd /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build/CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++  -isystem /home/wester/.conan2/p/zlib0d40682819e93/p/include -m64 -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c /home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/src/main.cpp
/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/src/main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/compressor.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wester/Projects/opt30/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/simple_cmake_project/build'
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```